# How to make each frame represent one second?

Tags: video, keyframes, frame-rate

I really want frames to represent seconds but how?

By watching a video I learned that doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> should do what I want but that didn't work. Because seconds are like 25 frames but if every frame was a second that would be cool.

Comment: You could change the frame rate of the video to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Properties window, then in the *Render* tab scroll down to the *Dimensions* section. The *Frame Rate* is the setting you want to change. From the dropdown choose *"Custom"* then in the new frame rate field that pops up enter 1.

[image: render settings in blender]